# Gulp create one JSON file from multiple JSON files

Tags: gulp

I'm using gulp and I want to create from multiple json files one json file.
each of my src file is object and the result should be array of all of the src object

### For Example:

#### src folder

- file1.json

  `{"id":1, "name":"1"}`
- file2.json

  `{"id":2, "name":"2"}`
- file3.json

  `{"id":3, "name":"3"}`

#### the result file should look like this

```
[ 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am going to suggest [gulp-merge-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge-json)

```
var merge = require('gulp-merge-json');

gulp.src(''./test/result/**/*.json'')
    .pipe(merge())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/json'));

});
```

It is cleaner code, more powerful and with much better documentation.  In your case a simple concat does work but look at gulp-merge-json it will intelligently combine json keys if necessary as well.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a gulp plugin [gulp-json-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-concat) that do that.

### Code Example

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const jsonConcat = require('gulp-json-concat');

gulp.task('concat-json', () => {
  const arr = [];
  return gulp.src('./test/result/**/*.json')
    .pipe(jsonConcat('result.json', function (data) {
      arr.push(data);
      return new Buffer(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/json'));

});
```